# Pure CSS star shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

There are a lot of CSS shapes shown on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). I am particularly surprised by the star:

[image: Star image]

How does the CSS below create this shape?

```css
#star-five {
  margin: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
#star-five:before {
  border-bottom: 80px solid red;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
#star-five:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

Comment: Three triangles positioned on top of each other and rotated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work?rq=1

Comment: How can we make those 5 points a bit rounded instead of sharp points

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Let's break it into pieces:

The yellow borders are actually set as `transparent` in the final product so they don't show. They are yellow here to show how the borders look.

As commented above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work?rq=1) shows the idea behind the basic triangle shape.

The div by itself:

```
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

[image: Piece one]

Combining the `:before` pseudo element is the same as this:

```
<div id="star-five">
    <div id="before"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Piece two]

Finally, combining the `:after` pseudo element is the same as this:

```
<div id="star-five">
    <div id="before"></div>

    <div id="after"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Piece three]

Now you overlap each element precisely using `position: absolute;` and rotate with `transform` as needed to get the final product:

[image: Final product]

Let's visualise it!

[image: Animation]

Comment: +1 really good presentation.

Comment: realy, it was awesomely represnetd. to make it clear and perfect in understanding

Comment: Awesome explanation and visualization.  thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a triangle using large borders, which is what is happening there. Then they're just rotating and positioning the triangles in a star pattern.